# Recording an action to define pattern CS3

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, cs3

I am trying to write an action in Photoshop CS3 to turn a bunch of images into patterns by running a batch. I was able to record an action to get this done, but they all have the same name as the image I used to first record the action. How can I get the newly created pattern to maintain it's name from the source file?

The steps I took once I created that action set are:
Open
Define pattern
Close

The close command isn't really working either, but I got around that when I ran the batch by selecting the "Override Action Open Command"

Comment: You can not, you need a script.

Comment: In that case is there an existing script that someone has? I have no experience writing scripts.